# Define looping condition array/object in syntax For loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, conditional-statements

When I loop an array or object I frequently use this way:

```
var arrCars = ["opel" , "audi" , "volvo" , "volkswagen" , 
              "renault" , "porsche" , "infinity" , "lexus"];

for (var i = 0, a; a = arrCars[i]; i++) {
  alert(a);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9mPj/)

It gives clear short code in my opinion instead of e.g. this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrCars.length; i++) {
  alert(arrCars[i]);
}
```

In this example it isn't a big issue but when there are some nested objects etc. it gives a lot code.

There are many syntax possibilities like you can see under this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript). But I still can't find out how I can loop trough a part of an array. For example, how can I loop only the first 3 values with my preferred syntax. Ofcourse i can use an extra condition statement, but I'm wondering how I can include this condition in the for syntax itself like: "*for (var i = 0;* **i < 4;** *i++){}*" if it's possible ofcourse.

Comment: I hate your preferred syntax - it's confusing to glance at when skimming ( just my opinion :) )

Comment: Your loop doesn't work if the array can contain `0`, `false`, or an empty string. Your second loop doesn't work at all, I think you forgot `i < arrCars.length`.

Comment: @tymeJV Maybe I like it because I use aliases often with SQL. For me it's orderly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0, a; ((a = arrCars[i]) || true) && i < 3; i++) {
    doStuff(a);
}
```

Wrapping the assignment in parenthesis makes sure the assignment doesn't turn into a boolean value, and then OR'ing that assignment's result with `true` makes sure that an element in the array that evaluates to `false` doesn't break your `for` loop. However at this point, that whole `for` loop line is pretty hideous in my opinion. I've always just done this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var a = arrCars[i];

    doStuff(a);
}
```

It's not quite as concise, but I've always preferred readability over compactness. Let the minifier take care of compacting things.

Comment: I get only **true** when I try your solution.

Comment: @Dinizworld that's what I get for answering from my phone without trying it! Edited.

Comment: @tophyr, I was already thinking in the direction of parentheses. I only tried it around the condition. After your edit it does exactly what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: I edited again to fix the "false" element problem, and made some commentary on how ugly that turned the whole line :) I personally prefer manually separating the `a` assignment from the `for` loop logic, though I did find your syntax in the OP intriguing (even if it makes this particular situation a pain).

Comment: Your first loop doesn't work if the array is shorter than 3 elements, it will use `undefined` for the missing elements. The `|| true` makes it ignore whether the element is there. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/VJ97Z/5/

Comment: @Barmar no different than `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { doSomething(arrCars[i]); }`. The OP referenced "the first 3 values", which is where my choice of list length came from - I don't think it's unreasonable to expect that the chosen iteration count should be valid.

Comment: The whole point of his style of looping is to use the existence of the element as part of the loop test, that's why he has `a = arrCars[i]` in the `for()` block. I interpreted his question as adding an _additional_ condition to limit to the first 3 elements, not remove the test of the element altogether. Otherwise, why put the assignment in the loop test at all?

Comment: I see what you mean with the original example but didn't see it that way with the "first 3 values" stipulation added. I saw the assignment mainly as a syntactic trick to perform the aliasing inside the `for` construct. Would be trivial to add a `&& i < arrCars.length` clause as well, but that'd just be ugly++.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like your syntax for the reasons I mentioned in a comment. But to answer the question:

```
for (var i = 0, a; i < 3 && (a = allCars[i]); i++)
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/VJ97Z/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the condition. Well, i'm always open for suggestions for improvement ;-).

Comment: It doesn't work. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VJ97Z/). Firebug says ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side.

Comment: Added parentheses and a fiddle demonstrating it

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the suggestions, what you want is this:

```
for (var i = 0, a; (a = arrCars[i]) && i < 3; i++) {
    ...
}
```

<del>It seems that you can't put the assignment anywhere other than the first spot (not even parentheses fix that) and</del> You need parentheses around it to prevent assignment to `arrCars[i] && i < 3`.

I do agree with other comments, you better not have an array item that evaluates to `false`.

Comment: You can put the assignment anywhere, parentheses DO fix it. See my answer.

Comment: Hmm, when I tried with parentheses it did not work.  I may have made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

```
var myArray = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
alert(i);
}
```

This will throw an alert message for your array elements 0 - 2 (first 3 in array)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the condition in my second example, it should be a working example how it can work without an array/object inside. Your solution is not what I was looking for.